# Refresh modified asset files on runtime in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, runtime

so i am modifying an .asset file during runtime and i would like to update it after i have changed it. It looks something like this:

```
            var lines = File.ReadAllLines(pathToAsset);

            if (Something)
            {
                lines[lines.Length - 3] = lines[lines.Length - 3].Replace(" []", "");
            }
            File.WriteAllLines(pathToAsset, lines);
```

Normally i could just say AssetDatabase.Refresh(), but that only works in Editor.

So after i have modified the file directly this way, i need to update it and i can't find anything online on how to do it on runtime. I would appreciate any help.

Comment: isnt this what unity made addressables for?

Comment: `Normally i could just say AssetDatabase.Refresh(), but that only works in Editor.` what exact asset are we talking about? Once the application is built all assets are read-only ... exception might be `StreamingAssets` on certain platforms and persistent data (which  would not refer to as assets)

Comment: Thanks you for your answers!
The code is from a colleague, so after clarifying more what he was trying to do and thanks to @derHugo's comment i have found another way. So the question can be counted as answered.